# Bond valuation question

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

Trying to solve the following question, but I am a bit stuck.

The 2IFM1 Corporation has two different bonds currently outstanding. Bond M has a face value of $\$20,000$ and matures in $20$ years. 
The bond makes no payments for the first $5$ years, then pays $\$1,200$ over the subsequent $8$ years and finally pays $\$1,500$ over the last $7$ years.

If the required return on both bonds is $6\%$, what is the current price for bond M? 
Anyone knows how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:

Bond Price = P = $$\frac{1200}{1.06^6}+\frac{1200}{1.06^7}+\cdots+\frac{1200}{1.06^{13}}+\frac{1500}{1.06^{14}}+\frac{1500}{1.06^{15}}+\cdots+\frac{21500}{1.06^{20}} = 15731$$

Thanks

Satish

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between bond M and N is blur! Anyway, this is a very elementary valuation question.

Say after T years, you will get paid - S units of money. Then the present value would be,

$\frac {S}{(1+r)^T}$. Where $r$ is your rate of interest rate. I have assumed that the interest rate is flat with time (term structure is flat). If it is not the case, then you have to use the term structure, and it would be little tedious. But in your case the term structure seems to be flat. Use the above formula for all future payments, calculate the total present value and you are done!

Comment: Sorry, bond N was another question. But I don't think your formula is right. However, answer should be "15731" But I don't know how to come there.

Comment: The formula is right.  You do know that the 1200 is paid **each** year for 8 years, and that the 1500  is paid **each** year for the last 7 years?

Comment: @user3055277 The answer is correct.